# Nucleosome wrapping direction

Tags: dna, nucleic-acids, histone, structure-prediction, supercoiling

Does anyone know which direction the nucleosomes are wrapped? I wonder:

1. Relative to the B-DNA double helix twist direction (right-hand)
2. Relative to the neighbor nucleosomes. Do they alternate to prevent supercoiling?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

B-form DNA is wrapped around histones in a **left-handed manner resulting in a left-handed solenoidal superhelix** (see [that](http://homepages.rpi.edu/~bellos/new_page_1.htm), [that](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Structural_Biochemistry/Nucleic_Acid/DNA/Supercoiling_and_Nucleosomes) and [this](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v436/n7047/full/nature03686.html?free=2)). The reason for this wrapping is that it reduces the helical tension. This [post](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/29918/why-do-most-organisms-have-negative-supercoiled-dna/30420#30420) has more information about DNA helical tension. Also note that exceptions exist (i.e. right-ended direction) especially for histone at the centromere as described in this [paper](http://jcb.rupress.org/content/186/4/453.full#ref-16).

For your second question, the exact way nucleosomes are then arranged to produce the chromatin fiber is, as far as I know, still not fully understood but the most accepted model is a zigzag arrangement ([Woodcock CL & Ghosh RP, 2010](http://cshperspectives.cshlp.org/content/2/5/a000596.full.html) and [Grigoryev SA & Woodcock CL](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=22394510)).